# IllegalArgumentException using Honeycomb compatibility package

Tags: android, compatibility, illegalargumentexception, android-support-library

I added the compatibility *.jar* to my project (the one to use fragments etc) but now every time I build my app Eclipse throws the error below. I added it by copying the *.jar* into the *libs/* folder and then used *Add Jar...* in the *Project Properties* dialog. Am I doing this right?

```
[TimetableHC] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:372)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:346)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:59)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:294)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:313)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:233)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:185)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:585)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:490)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:255)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:258)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:362)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:545)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:524)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:115)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:145)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:702)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:923)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1126)
[TimetableHC] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[TimetableHC] Dx 1 error; aborting
[TimetableHC] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: What android SDK version are you configured to build for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your described process is correct. However, the Android build tools think you have added it twice. Did you also add it as an Android library project that your project is referencing, or something?

Comment: Well I've tried it two different ways. If I copy it into the `/libs/` folder then reference it I get the error above, but if I use Add External Jar... instead of Add Jar... and click the original copy found in the SDK folder, I get `MethodNotFoundExceptions` so I don't really know what's going on.

Comment: somehow got it to work, think Eclipse was getting itself confused.

Comment: @Espiandev: Eclipse is easily confused. Of course, so am I. :-)